# How do I make a non-SpriteKit menu that transitions to a SpriteKit scene in OS X?

Tags: macos, sprite-kit, skscene

I am creating an OS X game and for my menu screen I would like to use UI elements like Pop Up Button cells, checkboxes, etc for my settings screen. How would I go about transitioning my view from the settings screen (a non-SpriteKit view) to a SpriteKit scene?

Comment: you can't transition to a skcene but a skview, and then it's the same process as transitioning from one uiviewcontroller to another, ie storyboard segues or uiview animations or similar

Comment: Any good resources for how to do this? I find there's a lot of stuff out there for iOS, but almost nothing for OS X :(